# My Content in Html is not fitting within the screen its overflowing out of the screen

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a Html page in which Navigation bar and footer adjust itself according to the screen width but my main content isn't adjusting itself.

I have apllied media query but it's for resolution of mobile(517 px) but when I tested it on a pc in another with less screen width it was overflowing

All the area within class"bhavya" is overflowing out of screen.

```css
  /* Making of Box 1 on Left for posts */

.box1 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 746px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  display: block;
}


/* Button to show more */

#myBtn {
  background-color: #08f;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 43px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show {
  display: none;
}


/* Styling Box For Search Box */

.search {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 384px;
  height: 130px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 828px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Search Written*/

.search h3 {
  margin-bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Style the search box */

.search input[type=text] {
  padding: 13px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 15px;
}


/* Style the button */

.search button[type=button] {
  background-color: #08f;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 43px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/* Recent Post Column */

.recent {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 384px;
  height: 850px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 220px;
  margin-left: 828px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}


/* img in recent */

#post1 {
  margin-right: 22px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  margin-top: 22px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 340px;
}


/* Text below */

.text1 {
  margin-right: 22px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
}


/* 2nd post */

#post2 {
  margin-right: 22px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  margin-top: 22px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 340px;
}


/* Text below */

.text2 {
  margin-right: 22px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
}


/* 3nd post */

#post3 {
  margin-right: 22px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  margin-top: 22px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 340px;
}


/* Text below */

.text3 {
  margin-right: 22px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  font-size: 22px;
}


/* Post Section fitting */

.container {
  width: 746px;
}

.container .row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(333.33px, 1fr));
}


/* Seperate Post*/

.container .row .col {
  margin: 20px;
  display: none;
}


/*post Image*/

.container .row .col .imgBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
}

.container .row .col .imgBox img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}


/*show more*/

.btn {
  padding: .7rem 2rem;
  background: royalblue;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  transition: .3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .search {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  .box1 {
    width: 384px;
    margin-top: 190px;
    height: fit-content;
  }
  .recent {
    display: none;
  }
  .container {
    width: 384px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0”>
  <meta content="Free HD Movie And Compressed Games Download From a High Speed Server, Try Now , One Click 
           Direct Download Link Available">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

  <title>GameMovieMania</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="heading"><b><i>GameMovieMania</i></b></h1> <br>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="games.html">Games</a>
    <a href="movies.html">Movies</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:java script/code.js;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>


  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
  </script>
  <div class="bhavya">

    <div class="search">
      <h3>Search</h3>
      <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search.." onkeyup="searchOn()">
      <button type="button"> Search </button>
    </div>

    <div class="recent">
      <h3>Recent Post</h3>
      <div class="post1">
        <a href="gta5.html">
          <img src="images/gta5.jpeg" id="img1">
          <p class="text1">Grand Theft Auto 5 | Free <br>Download | Highly Compressed </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="post2">
        <a href="gta4.html">
          <img src="images/gta4.jpeg" id="img2">
          <p class="text2">Grand Theft Auto 4 | Free <br>Download | Highly Compressed </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="post3">
        <a href="gta3.html">
          <img src="images/gta3.jpeg" id="img3">
          <p class="text3">Grand Theft Auto 3 | Free <br>Download | Highly Compressed </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <span class="box1"> 
                <div class="container">
                    <ul class="row">
                        <li class="col">
                            <div class="imgBox">
                                <img src="images/gta5.jpeg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                   Grand Theft Auto 5 Download | Free Download
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
    
                        <li class="col">
                            <div class="imgBox">
                                <img src="images/nowayhome.jpeg" alt="News">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    Spiderman No Way Home | Full Movie Download Hindi | 
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
    
                        <li class="col">
                            <div class="imgBox">
                                <img src="images/gta4.jpeg" alt="News">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    Grand Theft Auto 4 Download | Free Download
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                       
                        <li class="col">
                            <div class="imgBox">
                                <img src="images/shershaah.jpeg" alt="News">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    Shershaah Full movie download HD
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                       
                        <li class="col">
                            <a href="sooryavanshi.html">
                            <div class="imgBox">
                                <img src="images/sooryavanshi.jpeg" alt="News">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    Sooryavanshi Full Movie Download HD
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        </li>
    
                        <li class="col">
                            <div class="imgBox">
                                <img src="images/gta3.jpeg" alt="News">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    Grand Theft Auto 3 Download | Free Download
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
    
            
                        <li class="col">
                            <div class="imgBox">
                                <img src="1.jpg" alt="News">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    Android 11: Here are the 8 best new features
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
    
                        <li class="col">
                            <div class="imgBox">
                                <img src="2.jpg" alt="News">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    PHP 8 Release on November 2020
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
    
                        <li class="col">
                            <div class="imgBox">
                                <img src="1.jpg" alt="News">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    Android 11: Here are the 8 best new features
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
    
                        <li class="col">
                            <div class="imgBox">
                                <img src="2.jpg" alt="News">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    PHP 8 Release on November 2020
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
    
                        <li class="col">
                            <div class="imgBox">
                                <img src="1.jpg" alt="News">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    Android 11: Here are the 8 best new features
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
    
                        <li class="col">
                            <div class="imgBox">
                                <img src="2.jpg" alt="News">
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <h2 class="title">
                                    PHP 8 Release on November 2020
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <button class="btn">Load More</button>
                </div>
            
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $(".col").slice(0, 4).show()
                    $(".btn").on("click", function(){
    
                        $(".col:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown()
                        if ($(".col:hidden").length == 0) {
                            $(".btn").fadeOut('slow')
    
                        }
                    })
    
                    function searchOn() {
                        let input = document.getElementById('myInput').value
                        input=input.toLowerCase();
                        let x = document.getElementsByClassName('col');
                        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
                        if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
                        x[i].style.display="none";
                        }
                        else {
                        x[i].style.display="list-item";                 
                            }
                        }   
                    }
    
                </script>
            </span>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-basic">
    <footer>
      <div class="social">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon ion-social-instagram"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon ion-social-snapchat"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i>
        </a>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policies</a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="terms.html">Terms And Conditions</a></li>
      </ul>

      <p class="copyright">GameMovieMania Corp. © 2022</p>

    </footer>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please upload `style.css` file

Comment: it's all about CSS and the code you put has anything except CSS! make a snippet or fiddle and put it in your question.

Comment: @Jello uploaded now please help

Comment: @behzadmsalehi please help now

Comment: why you set huge margins to your divs inside bhavya ? why you set a fixed width for them?

Comment: Please do NOT ask us to visit your site in a question just to get visitors. That is considered SPAM and it has been closed and deleted as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this can some help
i added `display:grid` to your code and modified some of them

```css
body{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 20vh 20vh auto 20vh;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h"
    "b b s"
    "b b r"
    "f f f";
}
.header{
  grid-area: h;

}
.box1{
   grid-area: b;
    background-color: white;
/*     width: 746px; */
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    display: block;
  }

/* Button to show more */
#myBtn{
    background-color: #08f;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width: 80px;
    height: 43px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.show{
  display: none;
}

/* Styling Box For Search Box */
.search{
  grid-area: s;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 2px;
/*     width: 384px; */
    height: 170px; 
/*     float: right; */
    margin-top: 50px;
/*     margin-left: 828px; */
    display: block;
/*     position: absolute; */

}

/* Search Written*/
.search h3{
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    text-align: center;
}

  /* Style the search box */
.search input[type=text] {
    padding: 13px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 15px;
  }

  /* Style the button */
.search button[type=button] {
    background-color: #08f;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width: 80px;
    height: 43px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Recent Post Column */
.recent{
    grid-area: r;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 2px;
/*     width: 384px; */
    height: 100%;
/*     float: right; */
    margin-top: 220px;
/*     margin-left: 828px; */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
/*     position: absolute; */
}

/* img in recent */
#post1 {
    margin-right: 22px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    width: 340px;
    height: 340px;
}

/* Text below */
.text1 {
    margin-right: 22px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    font-size: 22px;
}

/* 2nd post */
#post2 {
    margin-right: 22px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    width: 340px;
    height: 340px;
}

/* Text below */
.text2 {
    margin-right: 22px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    font-size: 22px;
}

/* 3nd post */
#post3 {
    margin-right: 22px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    width: 340px;
    height: 340px;
}

/* Text below */
.text3 {
    margin-right: 22px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    font-size: 22px;
}

/* Post Section fitting */
.container {
/*   width: 746px; */
}

.container .row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(333.33px, 1fr));
}
/* Seperate Post*/
.container .row .col {
  margin: 20px;
  display: none;
}

/*post Image*/
.container .row .col .imgBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
}

.container .row .col .imgBox img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

/*show more*/
.btn {
  padding: .7rem 2rem;
  background: royalblue;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  transition: .3s;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}
.footer-basic{
  grid-area: f;
}
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .search{
      margin-top: 30px;
      border: px;
      margin-left: 50px;

  }
  .box1{
      width: 384px;
      margin-top: 190px;
      height: fit-content;
  }
  .recent{
      display: none;
  }
  .container {
    width: 384px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0”>
  <meta content="Free HD Movie And Compressed Games Download From a High Speed Server, Try Now , One Click 
       Direct Download Link Available">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

  <title>GameMovieMania</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
  <h1 class="heading"><b><i>GameMovieMania</i></b>

  </h1> <br>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="games.html">Games</a>
    <a href="movies.html">Movies</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:java script/code.js;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  </header>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
  </script>

    <div class="search">
      <h3>Search</h3>
      <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search.." onkeyup="searchOn()">
      <button type="button"> Search </button>
    </div>

    <div class="recent">
      <h3>Recent Post</h3>
      <div class="post1">
        <a href="gta5.html">
          <img src="images/gta5.jpeg" id="img1">
          <p class="text1">Grand Theft Auto 5 | Free <br>Download | Highly Compressed </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="post2">
        <a href="gta4.html">
          <img src="images/gta4.jpeg" id="img2">
          <p class="text2">Grand Theft Auto 4 | Free <br>Download | Highly Compressed </p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="post3">
        <a href="gta3.html">
          <img src="images/gta3.jpeg" id="img3">
          <p class="text3">Grand Theft Auto 3 | Free <br>Download | Highly Compressed </p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box1">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="row">
          <li class="col">
            <div class="imgBox">
              <img src="images/gta5.jpeg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title">
                Grand Theft Auto 5 Download | Free Download
              </h2>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="col">
            <div class="imgBox">
              <img src="images/nowayhome.jpeg" alt="News">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title">
                Spiderman No Way Home | Full Movie Download Hindi |
              </h2>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="col">
            <div class="imgBox">
              <img src="images/gta4.jpeg" alt="News">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title">
                Grand Theft Auto 4 Download | Free Download
              </h2>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="col">
            <div class="imgBox">
              <img src="images/shershaah.jpeg" alt="News">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title">
                Shershaah Full movie download HD
              </h2>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="col">
            <a href="sooryavanshi.html">
              <div class="imgBox">
                <img src="images/sooryavanshi.jpeg" alt="News">
              </div>
              <div class="content">
                <h2 class="title">
                  Sooryavanshi Full Movie Download HD
                </h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="col">
            <div class="imgBox">
              <img src="images/gta3.jpeg" alt="News">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title">
                Grand Theft Auto 3 Download | Free Download
              </h2>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="col">
            <div class="imgBox">
              <img src="1.jpg" alt="News">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title">
                Android 11: Here are the 8 best new features
              </h2>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="col">
            <div class="imgBox">
              <img src="2.jpg" alt="News">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title">
                PHP 8 Release on November 2020
              </h2>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="col">
            <div class="imgBox">
              <img src="1.jpg" alt="News">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title">
                Android 11: Here are the 8 best new features
              </h2>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="col">
            <div class="imgBox">
              <img src="2.jpg" alt="News">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title">
                PHP 8 Release on November 2020
              </h2>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="col">
            <div class="imgBox">
              <img src="1.jpg" alt="News">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title">
                Android 11: Here are the 8 best new features
              </h2>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="col">
            <div class="imgBox">
              <img src="2.jpg" alt="News">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="title">
                PHP 8 Release on November 2020
              </h2>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button class="btn">Load More</button>
      </div>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(".col").slice(0, 4).show()
        $(".btn").on("click", function() {
          $(".col:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown()
          if ($(".col:hidden").length == 0) {
            $(".btn").fadeOut('slow')
          }
        })

        function searchOn() {
          let input = document.getElementById('myInput').value
          input = input.toLowerCase();
          let x = document.getElementsByClassName('col');
          for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
              x[i].style.display = "none";
            } else {
              x[i].style.display = "list-item";
            }
          }
        }
      </script>
    </div>
    
  <div class="footer-basic">
    <footer>
      <div class="social">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon ion-social-instagram"></i>
        </p>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon ion-social-snapchat"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i>
        </a>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policies</a></li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="terms.html">Terms And Conditions</a></li>
      </ul>

      <p class="copyright">GameMovieMania Corp. © 2022</p>

    </footer>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS overflow property.

```
.bhavya {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Add vertical scrollbar */
}
```